# Symfony2 routing - exclude .html

Tags: symfony, routes

I want to to stop routes with a dot in Symfony2. So for example:

/blog/development (This is fine)
/blog/developm.ent (Need a 404)
/blog/development.html (Need a 404)

How can I achieve this using yml? This is what I have for the first example above:

```
s_nerds_blog_category_page:
    pattern: /blog/{category}
    defaults: { _controller: SNerdsBlogBundle:Default:category }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Route Requirements in symfony2:**

You can add regex **[requirements](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html#adding-requirements)** that the requested url needs to match to get resolved as a certain route:

```
# This example allows only digits (\d+) for {category} 

blog:
    path:      /blog/{category}
    defaults:  { _controller: AcmeBlogBundle:Blog:index, category: 1 }
    requirements:
        category:  \d+
```

**Exluding routes containing dots:**

```
# matches only routes not containing a dot

blog:
    path:      /blog/{category}
    defaults:  { _controller: AcmeBlogBundle:Blog:index, category: 1 }
    requirements:
        category:  ^[^\.]*$
```

**explanation**:

1. `^` - beginning of string
2. `[^\.]*` - any character except `.`, any number of repetitions
3. `$` - end of string